# How do I actually Print in the Console window the next Card?

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm having trouble actually printing the Card to the Console Window any ideas? Plus any suggestions on my code would be welcomed.

```
namespace Drinking_Game_
{
    class Program
    {
```

This Is where I'm having a bit of trouble. I can't get the card I called to print to the ConsoleWindow.

```
       public static void Main()
       {
           Deck deck = new Deck();
           Card card = new Card();
           deck.Shuffle();
           var value = deck.TakeCard();
           Console.WriteLine(value);
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
}




public enum Suit
{
    Spades = 0,
    Hearts = 1,
    Diamonds = 2,
    Clubs = 3,
}

public enum CardNumber
{
    Ace = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4,
    Five = 5,
    Six = 6,
    Seven = 7,
    Eight = 8,
    Nine = 9,
    Ten = 10,
    Jack = 11,
    Queen = 12,
    King = 13,
}

public class Card
{
    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
    public CardNumber CardNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Deck
{
    public Deck()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Cards = Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
            .SelectMany(s => Enumerable.Range(1, 13)
                                .Select(c => new Card()
                                {
                                    Suit = (Suit)s,
                                    CardNumber = (CardNumber)c
                                }
                                        )
                        ).ToList();
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        Cards = Cards.OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
    }

    public Card TakeCard()
    {
        var card = Cards.FirstOrDefault();
        Cards.Remove(card);

        return card;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Card> TakeCards(int numberOfCards)
    {
        var cards = Cards.Take(numberOfCards);

        var takeCards = cards as Card[] ?? cards.ToArray();
        Cards.RemoveAll(takeCards.Contains);

        return takeCards;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the default implementation of the `ToString()` method from the `Object` class that your `Card` implicitly inherits from.

For example:

```
public class Card
{
    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
    public CardNumber CardNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return CardNumber + " of " + Suit;
    }
}
```

Also, you should modify the `Suit` enum to be 1 through 4.

Comment: I tried that one but there is no suitable method found to override

Comment: Make sure you copy the method signature exactly as I typed it. For example, you might have accidentally typed `public override String` (note the capital `S`).

Comment: Matt first off thank you for taking the time to help me. I double checked my code and even tried copy/paste your code into mine. Still the same error.
Error 1 'Drinking_Game_.Card.Tostring()': no suitable method found to override

Comment: Change `Tostring()` to `ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to override tostring under the card class.

Comment: How do you go about doing  that?